# MongoMapper Embedded Documents

Tags: ruby, mongomapper

I have products as an embedded document inside the category class as shown below:

```
require 'mongo_mapper'

class Category

include MongoMapper::Document

key :Name, String
key :NumberOfProducts, Integer
many :products

end
```

and here is the Product class:

```
require 'mongo_mapper'

class Product

include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument

  key :Name, String

end
```

I am using the following code to display the Products but it says no method "Name" found.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongo'
require 'mongo_mapper'
require 'category'
require 'product'

include Mongo

MongoMapper.database = 'Northwind'

categories = Category.all()

categories.each{|category| puts category.Name

  unless category.Products.nil?

     category.Products.each{|product| puts product.Name}

  end


}
```

here is the error:

```
 undefined method `Name' for {"Name"=>"Amiga"}:BSON::OrderedHash (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first thing to try is that you have:

```
many :products
```

...but then you try to access it with `category.Products.each`

Definitely keep your naming consistent, and I'd recommend using ruby conventions (underscored, not camel cased, and certainly not capitalized camel case for non-classes).

So, maybe:

```
class Category
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :name, String
  many :products
end

class Product
  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument
  key :name, String
end


categories = Category.all
categories.each do |category|
  puts category.name
  category.products.each do |product|
    puts "  " + product.name
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks but I changed to Products instead of products since the MongoDb database serialized it as Products. Thanks again!

Comment: ? What mongodb serializes it as is irrelevant, you're using a Ruby plugin and you need to follow it's conventions (and it likely follows ruby conventions).

Comment: Actually the serialization was performed from the .NET (C#) side!

Comment: .NET side!? That is almost certainly your problem then :) I'd just write a little script using the bare-metal ruby driver to sanitize the data, in that case.

Comment: Basically .NET code writes to the MongoDb database and Ruby code reads the data. Just for FUN! :D

Answer (score 0):

The object you're getting back acts like a hash. In order to access the name you need to use `product["Name"]` or `category["Name"]`.

e.g.

```
irb(main):007:0> oh.baz
NoMethodError: undefined method `baz' for {"foobar"=>"baz"}:BSON::OrderedHash
    from (irb):7
irb(main):008:0> oh[:foobar]
=> "baz"
```

Comment: MongoMapper's EmbeddedDocument instantiates the appropriately named class with the data in the hashes when you use `many`. If you want just hashes you would use something like `key :products, Array, :default => []` and then `category.products << { :name => 'asdf' }`

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

```
@categories = Category.all
```

View

```
<% @categories.products.each do |product| %>
  <%= product.Name %> <br/>
<% end %>
```